# Which preposition is correct in this sentence - for it or with it?

Tags: grammar

Thank you for the gift card you sent me. I'm going to buy a new T-shirt for it.
OR I'm going to buy a new T-shirt with it.

Comment: "For it" would actually be "in exchange for it".

Comment: The multiple meanings of *for* are the basis of the joke "I got a new car for my wife...it was a pretty good trade!"

Answer (score 1):

"with it"

This is the standard meaning of "with": using as an instrument.

> cut with a knife. (wiktionary)

"For" would mean "benefiting"  You would say "I'm going to buy a new t-shirt for my mother."  It wouldn't make much sense to buy a t-shirt "for" a gift card — what would a gift card do with a t-shirt?